# Accessing posted Json data in php script

Tags: php, json, post, httprequest, laravel

I'm using the [Requests for PHP](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) library to POST some json data to another PHP script (I'm using Laravel's Response::json method to generate the json output:

```
public function postIndex()
{
    $input = Input::get();
    $data = Response::json($input);
    $url = 'http://mydomain.com/emails/events';
    $response = Requests::post($url, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'), $data);
    return $response->status_code;
}
```

I need the script on the receiving end (http://mydomain.com/emails/events) to decode and process the json, but I'm having a hard time accessing it. I setup a simple test script that emails me the contents of $_POST, but it comes up empty every time.

```
$post_data = print_r($_POST,true);
mail("my@email.com","post data",$post_data);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP do not parse Json POST. So you need to get raw post data like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Info about php [php wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Thank you I was able  to get it working with that then using json_decode  I was able to turn it into an array. Worked like a charm thank you.